# Have two XML files, need to make a query with XQuery and Java

Tags: java, xml, xquery

Need help with a homework assignment. I have two XML files: Person.xml and passedExams.xml

Person.xml form ->

```
<listWrapper>
   <items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="person">
      <address>Random street 2, Neverland</address>
      <telephoneNumber>555-1-612-9999</telephoneNumber>
      <name>Captain</name>
      <sid>35168589</sid>
      <surname>Obvious</surname>
    </items>
    <items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="person">
      <address>Random avenue, Neverland</address>
      <telephoneNumber>555-1-123-9999</telephoneNumber>
      <name>Gabe</name>
      <sid>36431731</sid>
      <surname>Newell</surname>
   </items>
 </listWrapper>
```

passedExams.xml form ->

```
<listWrapper>
   <items xsi:type="passedExams" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <id>
          <ExamID>BM3409</ExamID>
          <sid>36431731</sid>
      </id>
      <month>7</month>
      <grade>4</grade>
   </items> 
   <items xsi:type="passedExams" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <id>
           <ExamID>MV7402</ExamID>
           <sid>36441189</sid>
       </id>
       <month>7</month>
       <grade>4</grade>
   </items>
 </listWrapper>
```

Using those two files I'm trying to list all people who have passed x exams in y month of the year. For example, fetch all people who have passed 2 exams in 10th month of the year. I'm having trouble in writing a good query cause I'm not good with it. This is what I got so far:

```
for $exam in doc("pasedExams.xml")/listWrapper//items[month = 1]
where $person in doc("Person.xml")/listWrapper/items[$exam/sid = $person/sid] satisfies  (count($exam/sid) = 2)
return 
     <info>
        $person
     </info>
```

Here x = 1 and y = 2 just for the demo. The user can choose the parameters when the program starts. To clarify logic behind this, I'm trying to iterate through exams which have happened in January and then I'm trying to match SID (student ID) from the exam with one from Person.xml and then I'm counting the number of SID's occurrences in passedExams because the number of SID's occurrences is the number of passedExams by that student. When I run this in Stylus Studio is shows this error: *[DataDirect][XQuery][err:XPST0003]Error at line 2, column 14. Expected "return", but encountered "in".*

How can I make this work?

Comment: If you're asking homework stuff, please clearly state that. And since you already "wrote most of the code", please show this to us, otherwise this question will probably get closed. Often it helps to provide expected example output (for a limited number of input nodes) to avoid missunderstandings.

Comment: @Jens Erat Oh ok. Yeah it's a homework assignment. Well I edited the question and really tried my best to explain the problem and present what I have. Take a look now please.

Comment: for your next question: Please check your question for typos and valid XML first! It makes life much easier for people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @dirkk I'm sorry but I don't get how these XML's aren't valid. I did double check them but it's hard to keep an eye on details cause I was translating them from a foreign language to English.

Comment: @Larper: I fixed them (e.g. the closing </listWrapper> was missing). There is no need to translate your XML, just leave it in the original language - makes no difference in the query.

Comment: That's weird. I'm looking at XML documents right now in the original post and I see a </listWrapper>. Ok then! I thought it would make confusion since I was explaining what needs to be done in English so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error statement clearly states a syntax error in your code. You can not use that `in` construct in the where clause.
Also, you FWLOR expression does not represent what you want to achieve: You want to output all users, but you iterate over each exam although this is simply a required condition. So it should be more like that:

```
for $user in doc("Person.xml")/listWrapper/items
where count(doc("passedExams.xml")/listWrapper/items[id/sid = $user/sid and month = 1]) >= 2
return $user
```

I don't now, but I would guess that `grade` also determines if the person actually passed or failed the axam, so you might have to have another condition.

Comment: This doesn't work because in line 2, in a condition you are searching for month of the exam in Person.xml but it is located in passedExams.xml (at least I think that's the reason).

Comment: I just mixed up the two documents, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, it works almost perfectly. I noticed you used a condition ">= 2", but I need to find students who passed exactly, for example, 2 exams, so I guess it needs to be " = 2" in a condition? One more thing, that query doesn't work when searching for students who passed 0 exams in that month. If a person passed 0 exams in that month then his SID shouldn't be located in any of the <item> of passedExams.xml where month equals the month we are looking for. I tried but couldn't think of any modification that would solve that problem. Can you think of any?

Comment: You are right about ````= 2````. I don't see why the query should work with 0. What you describe is exactly what the where condition is doing (count the number of exams for this particular user and this particular month and compare it to 0)

Comment: Whoops! I'm sorry it seems I misunderstood something when checking for 0 exams, everything is working fine! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**You want something like this**:

```
let $numExams    := 0,
    $month       := 1,
    $Persons     := doc("file:///c:/temp/delete/Person.xml"),
    $PassedExams := doc("file:///c:/temp/delete/passedExams.xml")
 return
    for $p in $Persons/listWrapper/items
     return
        if($PassedExams/listWrapper/items
                     [xs:integer(month) eq $month and id/sid eq $p/sid]
                        [if($numExams gt 0)
                           then position() ge $numExams
                           else false()
                     ]
          or
           $numExams le 0
          and not($PassedExams/listWrapper/items
                          [xs:integer(month) eq $month and id/sid eq $p/sid])          )
           then
             (
              <info>
                {$p}
              </info>
              )
           else ()
```

**When this XQuery (and also a pure XPath 3.0 expression) is applied using the provided `Person.xml` (corrected from several malformations):**

```
<listWrapper>
   <items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="person">
      <address>Random street 2, Neverland</address>
      <telephoneNumber>555-1-612-9999</telephoneNumber>
      <name>Captain</name>
      <sid>35168589</sid>
      <surname>Obvious</surname>
    </items>
    <items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="person">
      <address>Random avenue, Neverland</address>
      <telephoneNumber>555-1-123-9999</telephoneNumber>
      <name>Gabe</name>
      <sid>36431731</sid>
      <surname>Newell</surname>
   </items>
</listWrapper>
```

**and on corrected and slightly modified `PassedExams.xml`:**

```
<listWrapper>
   <items xsi:type="passedExams" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <id>
          <ExamID>BM3409</ExamID>
          <sid>36431731</sid>
      </id>
      <month>1</month>
      <grade>4</grade>
   </items>
   <items xsi:type="passedExams" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <id>
           <ExamID>MV7402</ExamID>
           <sid>36441189</sid>
       </id>
       <month>7</month>
       <grade>4</grade>
   </items>
   <items xsi:type="passedExams" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <id>
          <ExamID>CL3102</ExamID>
          <sid>36431731</sid>
      </id>
      <month>1</month>
      <grade>4</grade>
   </items>
</listWrapper>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<info>
 <items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="person">
      <address>Random avenue, Neverland</address>
      <telephoneNumber>555-1-123-9999</telephoneNumber>
      <name>Gabe</name>
      <sid>36431731</sid>
      <surname>Newell</surname>
 </items>
</info>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However it's not working as it should to. It seems to work except when you search for people who have passed 0 exams in a certain month. This query lists people who HAVE passed an exam in that month (it doesn't filter them out). If a person hasn't passed an exam in a given month their SID wouldn't be in any <item> of passedExams.xml which has that month. How would one filter that? (Given the structure of these XML files does searching for students who passed 0 exams in a certain month even make sense?)

Comment: @Larper, Please, see the answer -- updated now.

Comment: Thanks, this works too in Stylus Studio but I chose to accept @dirkk 's answer cause his solution is working in Java. Yours throws this [error report](http://pastebin.com/Ng2FQaXp). In case you're wondering what my Java code looks like and maybe you're interested in fixing the problem for future reference, this is my [code](http://pastebin.com/dbh41mcq). Cheers!

Comment: @Larper, This is pure XQuery/XPath and is not dependent on any other programming language, such as Java. Dirk's solution also doesn't have anything "Java" in it. This means that you either have problems properly invoking the XQuery engine from Java, or that this engine is buggy. I have tested this code with Saxon 9.4.03. It also runs correctly with BaseX.

Comment: Yeah I know the problem is on my side, I'm doing something wrong. Maybe my code can't run 3.0 Xpath or something? I'm using parts of the code from class and I remember professor talking how XQuery is using XPath 2.0

Comment: This is an *XQuery 1.0* solution. The fact that it also happens to be an XPath 3.0 expression is irrelevant.